# Two root modules registered in platformBrowserDynamic?

Tags: angular

If to bootstrap two Angular application on the page using:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Then place two root components from each root module:

```
<app-root></app-root>
<app-root></app-root>
```

Does it create a two different not intersecting applications? Or second module + root component will override previous?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap two apps in same page using angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44948763/bootstrap-two-apps-in-same-page-using-angular-2)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple root modules on angular application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55538438/multiple-root-modules-on-angular-application)

Comment: These answers about loaded two different modules, I ask about the same modules

Comment: If for whatever strange reason, you want to load the same app twice, you'd have to make a copy of your app.module and give the second one a different name and change the app-root selector to something unique. otherwise it won't work (your example won't give you the same app twice).

Comment: Could I clone appModule, or issue is in module name? It is strange case when I want to configurate two the same application but with different config.

Comment: If use have copy of module with different name but use shared component in both modules, is it broblem? Or each module incapsulate own instance of component?